# Почему PhpStorm 10.0.1 зачеркивает функции с префиксом mysql_?

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

PhpStorm не распознает код mysql. Если просто сохраняю проект в notepad то все работает, а когда тот же проект копирую (пишу) в PhpStorm, он зачеркивает команды подключения к mysql. На скрине видно:

[image: screen]

PhpStorm настроен с openserver. Может в этом проблема? Что-то еще нужно добавить?
Хотя если прямо подключиться к БД из PhpStorm, то все работает нормально.

Comment: Если какой-то из ответов был вам полезен, вы можете его отметить как решение - галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: А я вообще пишу в текстовом редакторе) там точно нету некаких зачеркиваний) И все работает на отлично.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Выдержка из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php):

> Внимание
>   Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет удалено в будущем.
>   Используйте вместо него [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Прислушайтесь к процитированному совету.

Относительно вашего вопроса: таким образом PhpStorm сигнализирует о том, что вы пытаетесь использовать устаревшие функции, которые будут в будущем удалены.

Эти предупреждения никак не влияют на функциональность вашего приложения. Если не работает подключение к базе данных, вам следует проверить используемую версию PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Эти функции в `php` являются устаревшими и начиная с какой-то версии удалены или будут удалены... поэтому и зачеркнуты

например
`mysqli_client_encoding` -  функция была помечена УСТАРЕВШЕЙ начиная с версии PHP 5.3.0 и была УДАЛЕНА в версии PHP 5.4.0.

`mysql_connect` - Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.

и так далее

Comment: А как можно исправить это ? я изучаю php 5.3 там они же есть ? как заставить phpstrom работать с этими функциями ?

Comment: @Hovo А что, вам он не дает выбрать эти функции? Он просто вам их зачеркивает, показывая, что не желательно их использовать. Но использовать то их вы можете не смотря на это. Попробуйте в настройках шторма поставить версию php 5.3

Answer (score 3):

Потому-что библиотека mysql устарела, теперь mysqli надо использовать